# lighttpd server not serving images, js or css files

Tags: lighttpd, http-server

I am given a try to [lighttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net/).
I configured a server with the instructions I found [here](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/TutorialConfiguration).

Below my configuration file:

```
server.document-root = "<my_site_directory>" 

server.port = 4000

server.username = "www" 
server.groupname = "www"

mimetype.assign = (
  ".html" => "text/html", 
  ".txt" => "text/plain",
  ".jpg" => "image/jpeg",
  ".png" => "image/png"
)

static-file.exclude-extensions = ( ".fcgi", ".php", ".rb", "~", ".inc" )
index-file.names = ( "index.html" )
```

However, the images do not appear on the browser. The same seems to happen with css and js files. Since my images are in svg format, I tried adding to the mime types: `".svg" => "image/svg"` but it did not help.

If I debug it using Chrome developer tools, I can see that for each image, css and js file I have this error:

```
"Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED "
```

Just in case, I tried changing the `server.username` property to my user name (in case it is a problem of permits) but it did not help.

Comment: What kind of response code or error page are you getting when you try to directly access one of those files in your browser?

Comment: If I directly write the url of the svg image, it is downloaded

Comment: Are the wrong mime types being sent or something, then?  Can you use debugging tools in your browser (F12 in chrome) to determine why it's not happy with those resources?

Comment: I do not see anything strange with the developer tools. But maybe I am not looking in the right places.

Comment: Network tab, the lines for the individual resources that are having problems?

Comment: Found it. For each image, js and css file I have this error: "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED "

Comment: Are those pointed to a different hostname or connection port in the URLs for the resources?

Answer (score 3):

Finally fixed, the problem was indeed wrong MIME types. I added:

```
".js" => "text/javascript",
".css" => "text/css",
```

and replaced the wrong `".svg" => "image/svg"` by `".svg" => "image/svg+xml"`

Answer (score 1):

FYI - according to [RFC 4329](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4329.txt) the proper MIME type for .js files should be "application/javascript".